# Laravel different selects in one query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I will try to describe my situation; I have two separate queries below:

```
   public function getDriversCount($request) {
      return Driver::count();
   }
```

and the second one:

```
public function getDriversCountWithStatus($request) {
    return Driver::select('status', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                        ->groupBy('status')
                        ->get();
}
```

now we can see that these two are two separate functions and to separate queries. In the first one I am counting the whole `drivers` table records, but in the second one I am counting according to `status` groups. So how can I achieve the same result by one function and one query? something like that:

```
{
    "absolute_total": 21,
    "with_status": [
        {
            "status": 0,
            "total": 11
        },
        {
            "status": 1,
            "total": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

this one I received manually by calling these two functions separately.

Comment: Stricktly speaking, you cannot get both counts in one query. You can combine the two with subqueries and union into one, but it is not going to be very efficient. Technically, you can do the count by status as a single query, then add up the subcounts to get the total count in php.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below, we set an empty array at the start, so if the function returns an empty array you can do further checking on that:

```
public function getDriversCountAndStatus($request)
{
    // Set the array that will be returned
    $driversCountWithStatus = [];

    // Get the driver count
    $driverCount = Driver::count();

    // Get the driver status
    $driverStatus = Driver::select('status', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                    ->groupBy('status')
                    ->get();

    // Combine the driver count and status into one array
    $driversCountWithStatus = [
        "absolute_total" => $driverCount,
        "with_status" => $driverStatus;
    ];

    return $driversCountWithStatus;
}
```

Comment: He wants to do just one query, i don't think your answer will help OP.

Comment: I read it as he wants one function, but if he wants one query, then I can update above, we'll see what he says

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet because I don't have enough rep.

I think I understand what you mean. The easiest way to do this would be chaining a couple of selects together.

Something like

```php
public function getDriversCountWithStatus($request) {
    return Driver::select('total', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->addSelect('status', DB::raw('count(*) as total group by status'))
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: No but I'm not sure there's a method for doing it in one statement. Unless he tries PDO?